# website cookies not being recognized by php

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a cookie I set when a user logs into my website and I also have a session ID for them, the only trouble right now is that the cookie I set doesn't seem to be able to be accessed. Although I can access the PHPSESSID cookie.

User Login:

```
$_SESSION['user_is_loggedin'] = 1;
setcookie('usr',  $usr->username, time()+3600*24*7, '/');
```

Accessing the cookie:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_is_loggedin']) && $_SESSION['user_is_loggedin'] == 1 ) { 
    echo $_COOKIE['usr'];
```

error:
`Undefined index: usr`

I understand why it would error without setting the cookie, but it still errors even WITH the cookie set.

**EDIT** It seems that after I refresh the page the session exists but after that it clears the session. Do sessions not carry over after a page refresh?

Comment: Have you manually verified that the cookie exists in your web console?

Comment: yes, I have verified it exists, and I try to access it after refreshing the page or going somewhere else. The first time the page refreshes it works fine but after that it doesnt work EDIT: after more testing, it seems to only work about 30% of the time when I refresh the page for the first time after clearing the cookies and then logging in again.

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['user_is_loggedin'], $_COOKIE['usr']) && $_SESSION['user_is_loggedin'] == 1 ) { 
 echo $_COOKIE['usr'];

Comment: Cookie is only available in the `$_COOKIE` array on the next request. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I figured it out, it was the session. I had not started the session before the <html> tag on the page

Comment: regarding your page refresh, are you calling `session_start();` at the top of your script?

Comment: @Rob M. yea that was the issue, if you want to post it to as an answer I'll accept it so this thread has an answer

Comment: @Duck you figured it out, post and accept your own answer

Comment: @scrowler, I'd rather give it to someone else

Comment: @Duck you're a giver, nice work. +1 on your question for your efforts anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `session_start();` and setting your cookie at the top of your script, not doing so will send headers and cause `session_start()` and `setcookie()` to fail.

Also, as @MiloLaMar pointed out, if you had error_reporting turned on you would've seen that it was failing:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: While we're making shots in the dark, you could always `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `ini_set('error_level', E_ALL);` during development. Just remember not to let that face the public.

Comment: Fair point @MiloLaMar, but it wasn't a shot in the dark. We had worked through their issue in the comments

Comment: I see how it followed from the comments now. I just made that comment on your answer to try to save @Duck some time when other errors occur.

Comment: Yes sir, I've added your comment to my answer for anyone passing by. Thanks!